# How do I search the readme of repositories using Github Search API?

Tags: github, github-api

My objective is to count the number of repositories that use PyTorch. Therefore, I came up with the following code, using the THUNDER CLIENT extension in VS Code -

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=language:python + readme:PyTorch
```

However, this gives me just 7 search results. I am confident the result should be in the range of thousands. Could someone suggest where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The GitHub search API for repositories checks the name, description and the README of all repositories.

Therefore, all that was needed to be done was -

```
https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=PyTorch
```