# The GitHub search can't search on repository's README

Tags: github, search

I'm searching on GitHub for the keywords: "**HPV**", and "**virus**" with nextflow language. And hoping my search result has the repo [nf-VIF](https://github.com/bioinfo-pf-curie/nf-vif/). Cause in nf-VIF repo's README file has these keywords.

[image]

However, it returns just another result with keywords mapped with the description part. I also tried searching by Github Search API according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74363221/how-do-i-search-the-readme-of-repositories-using-github-search-api). But it still not worked (https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=HPV+virus).

[image]

Could someone tell me how to search repo based on README in GitHub, please? Thanks.

Comment: That sounds likea good question for Github's user support

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the search phase to use is "HPV and virus and nextflow in:readme" without quotes. see https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/github-search-tips/ for where I found the answer. search string used on google to find website "search readme file github"